# Lyx not hyphenating properly, text running off page

Tags: lyx, hyphenation

I have similar problem in LyX as already been asked by another user for LaTeX. As you can see in the attached file that the text is running off the page. I already have tried following help but it didn't work in my case:
https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/TextAppearance#avoidHyphenationWords

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem in LyX?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Insert explicit hyphenation points, like this: `(3-glycid\-oxy\-propyl)\-tri\meth\-oxy...`. TeX is reluctant to hyphenate words that already contain hyphens.

Comment: Following up on @gernot's comment, in LyX you do that with Insert --> Formatting --> Hyphenation point (Ctrl + -).

Comment: thanks for your answers. I am following "Insert --> Formatting --> Hyphenation point". It works really good

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think you could paste your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases LaTeX does not know how to hyphenate a word, and then it can be helped along by explicitly marking up hyphenation points. In LaTeX code this is done by `\-`, e.g. `(3-glycid\-oxy\-propyl)\-tri\meth\-oxy...`.

In LyX you do this with Insert --> Formatting --> Hyphenation point (keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>).